Issue with authentication recaptcha token
I have an Angular website base where I'm just working on the whole authentication workflow using Firebase. The workflow I choose is to signup using email and then requesting the phone number to enable the MFA function. I have this code already in production and is working under one project in Firebase but not another new one I created where I get a 400 error. I compared basically all the configuration options and cannot see any difference.
I get the error upon calling phoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber() with the recaptcha.
Like I said same code works with the old firebaseConfig but when I use the new project all the sudden fails consistently.

